# извлечь значение rgba() из строки с помощью regex в JQ

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

как извлечь только rgba(0,0,0,0.5) из строки ниже используя regex и применить к какому либо элементу. при этом, значения в скобке можно было менять на любые

```
var rgba = 'ыовоы rgba(0,0,0,0.5)-2981'
```

Answer (score 0):

Извлекаем и используем (в console.log)

```
    const regex = /rgba\((\d+)\,(\d+)\,(\d+)\,((\d|\.)+)\)/gm;
    const str = `ыовоы rgba(0,0,0,0.5)-2981`;
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        });

        console.log("мы можем использовать полностью выдранное", m[0]);
        var newStr = "rgba(" + m[1] + "," + m[2] + "," + m[3] +"," +(parseFloat(m[4]) * 2).toFixed(1) +")";
        console.log("мы можем собрать новое с в 2 раза меньше прозграчности :", newStr);
    }
```